# Azure blob version retention details using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage

I am trying to find all blob versions in a container with its retention period. Basically we want to get this data to see what can be deleted from blob versions. I can see retention period of versions in Azure portal but not in PowerShell. I am trying below script. Can someone please guide me how can I get the same details using PowerShell?

```
Connect-AzAccount

Set-AzContext -Subscription "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

$resourceGroup = "rg-dev-001"
$storageAccountName = "stdev"
$containerName = "offload"

$stoaccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -Name $storageAccountName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup

$versions = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $containerName -Context $stoaccount.Context -IncludeVersion -IncludeDeleted | where { $_.IsLatestVersion -NE 'True' }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can see the retention period of versions in the Azure portal but not in PowerShell.

In my environment, I have a file with a retention period and another file that doesn't have a retention period.

**Portal:**

[image]

You can use the below PowerShell script to retrieve information.

**Command:**

```
Connect-AzAccount

Set-AzContext -Subscription "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

$resourceGroup = "rg-dev-001"
$storageAccountName = "stdev"
$containerName = "offload"

$stoaccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -Name $storageAccountName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup

$versions = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $containerName -Context $stoaccount.Context -IncludeVersion -IncludeDeleted 

Foreach($version in $versions){
   $properties = $version.BlobClient.GetProperties()
   Write-Host "URL: $($version.Context.BlobEndPoint)$($version.Container.Name)/$($version.Name)"
   Write-Host "TYPE: $($properties.Value.BlobType)"
   Write-Host "SIZE: $($properties.Value.ContentLength / 1KB) KiB"
   Write-Host "VERSION ID: $($properties.Value.VersionId)"
   Write-Host "RETENTION PERIOD: $($properties.Value.ImmutabilityPolicy.ExpiresOn)"
   write-Host " "
   }
```

**Output:**

```
URL: https://venkat789.blob.core.windows.net//example.pdf
TYPE: Block
SIZE: 22.166015625 KiB
VERSION ID: 2023-09-11T15:05:29.3224280Z
RETENTION PERIOD: 12/20/2023 15:06:41 +00:00
 
URL: https://venkat789.blob.core.windows.net//table403 (1).txt
TYPE: Block
SIZE: 0.376953125 KiB
VERSION ID: 2023-09-11T15:19:15.9233123Z
RETENTION PERIOD:
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Manage block blobs with PowerShell - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/blob-powershell#reading-blob-properties)